# A homomorphism $f:S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove that $f$ must be trivial.

Tags: group-theory

A homomorphism $f:S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove that $f$ must be trivial, i.e., $\ f(\sigma) = 0 \ \forall \sigma \in S_{n}$.

I started off by thinking that it was something to do with the fact that (for $n>2$) $S_{n}$ is not abelian, and $\mathbb{R}$ is.  But I can't find a way to reach a conclusion.

Alternatively I looked at $f(\sigma \tau) = z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(\sigma)f(\tau)=xy \in \mathbb{R}$ but again, can't find a way to draw a conclusion.

Comment: from the homomorphism property, $f(\sigma\tau) = f(\sigma)f(\tau)$, we have the special case $f(\sigma ^n) = (f(\sigma))^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ this requires that any element $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the homomorphism must have finite order.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is the group of real numbers under addition or under multiplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, if you like, we can view this as a consequence of $S_n$'s particular relationship to abelianness: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is abelian, any homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has in its kernel the commutator subgroup of $S_n$; put another way, any such homomorphism factors through the "abelianization"  of $S_n$. For $n \geq 2$, this abelianization is the sign map from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and as there are no elements of $\mathbb{R}$ (in the additive sense) of order $2$, the only possible homomorphism is accordingly the zero map.

Phrasing the same argument differently: the symmetric group is generated by transpositions, which are elements of order 2. These must be mapped under homomorphism to elements of order some factor of 2 (i.e., either elements of order 2 or the identity). As noted above, $\mathbb{R}$ has no elements of order 2, and thus every transposition must be mapped to zero, and thus every permutation in general must be mapped to zero.

Phrased even more abstractly: any homomorphism into a torsion-free group must send all torsion elements to zero; in particular, any homomorphism from a finite group to a torsion-free group must be the zero map.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there was some $\sigma \neq \text{id}$ such that $f(\sigma) \neq 0$. Then $\sigma$ has some finite order, say $k$. Because $f$ is a homomorphism we have $k \times f(\sigma) = 0$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This clearly is a contradiction.

Comment: Note that tou can phrase the same argument without contradiction: the defining property of morphisms implies that a torsion element (i.e. one of finite order) is sent to another torsion element; as $0$ is the only torsion element in $(\mathbb R,+)$, we're done.